# implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an objective-c pointer with ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm Working on a project that uses ARC and I am having trouble with an existing piece of code that I already had.

heres the code:

```
- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        errorPointer =  error; //Getting error here
    }

    return self;
}
```

Im getting an error that says:

> implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an objective-c pointer to 'NSError' is disallowed with ARC.

What should I do to fix this problem? I've tried doing a bridged cast, but didn't work.
Any help is appreciated.

Oh and just for clarification, in the .h file this is how I declared the variable errorPointer:

> NSError *errorPointer;

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be

```
errorPointer = *error; // no error here
```

The two variables differ by a level of indirection (simply speaking, the number of stars in their declaration is not the same). You need to add an `*` in front of the `error` to offset the extra `*` of the `errorPointer`.

Comment: @AdamW Absolutely, you are correct! I got confused because of the naming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

errorPointer and error have mismatched types.

Based on the code you have there, it seems like your `error` argument should just be declared as `NSError *`.

Comment: Just to expand slightly, the only reason to use a double indirection argument (`NSError **`) would be if you needed to allocate the error within that init method and have it be available to the caller.

Comment: Yes, and that's a common pattern in Cocoa methods. Many Cocoa framework methods return an error (if any) via a passed-by-reference `NSError *` argument to the method.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen For sure...but in this case it's not apparent that he wants to do that, hence my suggestion to just change the argument's type.